# Error when trying to install Django using pip on Windows 10

Tags: python, django, windows, installation, pip

I am new to Python and encountering an error while trying to install the Django framework on my Windows machine using pip. The error message I receive is:

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install django
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I'm unsure about the cause of this error and how to resolve it. As a beginner, I would appreciate detailed guidance on how to fix this issue.

What I've tried:

- Checked that Python is installed correctly on my system.
- Verified that the PATH environment variable includes the directory where Python and pip are installed.
- Attempted to run the command in both Command Prompt and PowerShell.

[It is a screen-shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbK6X.png)

Comment: Do you have pip installed? How did you install python?

Comment: @ViaTech Yeah pip is installed. I installed it in Pycharm. And python manually by its website.

Comment: Unless you plan to use Python-based, pip-installed tools to a great extent, you should run it through Python: `python -m pip install django`. On a system with more than one python, this can cause some surprising problems https://bugs.python.org/issue22295 (most notably path ordering and having the same Python first as what pip is using)

Comment: @RivenSkaye ok I will try what you said. And thanks for yourhelp